# German Bank Account: Deutsche vs CommerzBank

Tags: germany, banking

I'll be arriving shortly in Germany for Work and my company has asked me to tell them my preferred bank to arrange an appointment. I'm looking at various options and Commerz Bank seems to quite good however I have few questions:

1. Where does it mention that if I have incoming 1200Euro per month, there's no fee? And also what does it mean by incoming amount per month, do I need to maintain that balance monthly at all times or just a deposit of 1200 per month is enough but I'm free to use it as I wish? Say 1200E was deposited into the account and I can then either withdraw it completely from ATM or whatever. It still wouldn't count towards fee, right?
2. Second, all their prices are listed in German. Can some one tell me their Credit Card annual fee compared to Deutsche Bank? Also usually what are the allowed limits on Credit Cards usually between Standard vs Gold etc. in Germany?
3. My company is saying that Deutsche Bank will offer no fee for running account for their employees but I'll have to pay for Credit Cards and Rent Deposit accounts etc. which I'm assuming lower and free respectively in case of CommerzBank. So overall my current assumption is that CommerzBank will be cheaper in the long run compared to Deutsche Bank even if they are offering free account maintenance fee.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the two banks direct?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s essentially about price-shopping / financial advice